# Is there a way to detect True to False transitions in python?

Tags: python, boolean, boolean-logic

I am using the code below to detect transitions from False to True.  I need  separate code that only detects changes from True to False.  Is there a way to do this with the current code below?

```
test = [True, False, False, True, True, False, True, True, False, False, False, True]

class EdgeDetector:
     """Detects False to True transitions on an external signal."""

     def __init__(self, reader, action):
         self.reader = reader
         self.action = action
         self.last_value = reader()    # initialise value

     def test(self):
         new_value = self.reader()
         if new_value and not self.last_value:
         self.action()
         self.last_value = new_value

 # simple self-test
 if __name__ == '__main__':
     vlist = test
     vgen = (v for v in vlist)              # generator for value sequence

     def test_reader():                     # generate test sequence
        value = next(vgen)
        print("Read:", value)
        return value

     def printer():
        print("Phase transition")

    test_subject = EdgeDetector(test_reader, printer)
    for i in range(len(vlist)-1):
         test_subject.test()
```

Note:  This is not my code.  I am using the code provided from this thread: [How to execute a function once when boolean value changes in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43272049/how-to-execute-a-function-once-when-boolean-value-changes-in-python)

I can't post in that thread to ask a follow up question.
Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here `if new_value and not self.last_value:`

So the first part is looking for if new_value has a Truthy value. AND it's looking for if self.last_value has a Falsey value. This gets muddy when you start comparing two different booleans to each other.

The first part is really looking to see if there is a value in new_value. So we can instead compare it to none. The second part is really looking to see if the two booleans match, so we can just compare them to each other.

Update the line to this, and it should work for transitions in either direction.

`if new_value is not None and new_value is not self.last_value:`

**Edit:**

As per your comments:
There are a couple ways we can track what the phase transitions are with out having to look up each one.

**Option One:**

Using one function to track both transition to false from true and to true from false. We can pass the value back to the printer function.

```
def test(self):
    new_value = self.reader()
    if new_value is not None and new_value is not self.last_value:
        self.action(new_value) # Note here we are passing a value back

    self.last_value = new_value
```

Now we just add to the printer function to see the changes.

```
def printer(transition):
   print(f"Phase transition to: {transition}")
```

**Finalized Code Option 1:**

```
test = [True, False, False, True, True, False, True, True, False, False, False, True]

class EdgeDetector:
     """Detects False to True transitions on an external signal."""

     def __init__(self, reader, action):
         self.reader = reader
         self.action = action
         self.last_value = reader()    # initialize value

     def test(self):
         new_value = self.reader()
         if new_value is not None and new_value is not self.last_value:
             self.action(new_value)

         self.last_value = new_value



# simple self-test
if __name__ == '__main__':
    vlist = test
    vgen = (v for v in vlist)              # generator for value sequence

    def test_reader():                     # generate test sequence
       value = next(vgen)
       print("Read:", value)
       return value

    def printer(transition):
       print(f"Phase transition to: {transition}")

    test_subject = EdgeDetector(test_reader, printer)
    for i in range(len(vlist)-1):
        test_subject.test()
```

**Option Two:**

This is the way to do it if you want separate code for transitions from false to true and for from true to false.

First in the EdgeDetector class we need to modify the **init** as so:

```
def __init__(self, reader, action_true, action_false): #Note the second action here
    self.reader = reader
    self.action_true = action_true
    self.action_false = action_false # We set it just like the previous one.
    self.last_value = reader()
```

Then we can update the test code.

```
def test(self):
    new_value = self.reader()
    if new_value is not None and new_value is not self.last_value:
        if new_value:
            self.action_true()
        else:
            self.action_false()

    self.last_value = new_value
```

Then we modify the printer statement and add a second one:

```
def printer_true():
    print("Phase transition to true")
    
def printer_false():
    print("Phase transition to false")
```

Finally the initialization of EdgeDetector needs to be updated.

```
test_subject = EdgeDetector(test_reader, printer_true, printer_false)
```

**Finalized Code for Option 2**

```
test = [True, False, False, True, True, False, True, True, False, False, False, True]

class EdgeDetector:
     """Detects False to True transitions on an external signal."""

     def __init__(self, reader, action_true, action_false):
         self.reader = reader
         self.action_true = action_true
         self.action_false = action_false
         self.last_value = reader()    # initialize value

     def test(self):
         new_value = self.reader()
         if new_value is not None and new_value is not self.last_value:
             self.action(new_value)

         self.last_value = new_value



# simple self-test
if __name__ == '__main__':
    vlist = test
    vgen = (v for v in vlist)              # generator for value sequence

    def test_reader():                     # generate test sequence
       value = next(vgen)
       print("Read:", value)
       return value

    def printer_true():
       print(f"Phase transition to true")

    def printer_false():
       print(f"Phase transition to false")

    test_subject = EdgeDetector(test_reader, printer_true, printer_false)
    for i in range(len(vlist)-1):
        test_subject.test()
```

Comment: Thank you for the assistance.  The problem I will run into with the above change is it will generate too many signals. It will be difficult to distinguish between why it changed without manually looking into the reason.

Comment: Are you only wanting false to true changes?

Comment: Yes and I need code that only looks for true to false changes. I want two different codes, so it can generate two different types of signals. The data sets fed into each code will be different. Sorry for the confusion on the original post. I edited it slightly

Comment: I edited the answer and provided some more details. That help better?

Comment: Yes exactly what I needed.  Thank you, sorry for the confusion on the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Idea: you need to detect False , True pattern, the expression is `~a & b`.
To align input, use input[1:] and input[:-1], so `~input[:-1] & input[1:]`.

```py
test = [True, False, False, True, True, False, True, True, False, False, False, True]

def edge_detector(inp):
    import numpy as np
    inp = np.array(inp)
    return np.arange(len(inp)-1)[~inp[:-1] & inp[1:]]

print(edge_detector(test))
```

Answer (score 0):

It's quite easy to do with Pandas:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['test'] = [True, False, False, True, True, False, True, True, False, False, False, True]

df['going_true'] = df['test'].apply(int).diff() == 1
df['going_false'] = df['test'].apply(int).diff() == -1

df
     test  going_true  going_false
0    True       False        False
1   False       False         True
2   False       False        False
3    True        True        False
4    True       False        False
5   False       False         True
6    True        True        False
7    True       False        False
8   False       False         True
9   False       False        False
10  False       False        False
11   True        True        False
```

Note that it doesn't flag the first `True`, but that can be desired behavior for edge detection.

Numpy also has a diff function, but it will remove one element rather than place a `NaN` at the top.  This could confuse your indexing.